# How to store a stream in a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop, stream

Here is my script:

```
for country in AT DE GB IT NO ZA
do
    info1=$(cat /path/to/big.log* | grep $country | wc -l)
    info2=$(cat /path/to/other-big.log* | grep $country | wc -l)
    echo $country $info1 $info2
done
```

This works but is really slow...

I have tried this script instead by putting the file reading out of the loop:

```
data1=$(cat /path/to/big.log*)
data2=$(cat /path/to/other-big.log*)
for country in AT DE GB IT NO ZA
do
    info1=$(echo $data1 | grep $country | wc -l)
    info2=$(echo $data2 | grep $country | wc -l)
    echo $country $info1 $info2
done
```

But now the script doesn't work. What am I missing ?

Comment: `grep` is a good idea for increasing speed when we want to extract specific expressions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good idea to storing the whole file content into variable. You can try this `bash` script,

```
for country in AT DE GB IT NO ZA
do
    info1=$(grep $country /path/to/big.log* | wc -l)
    info2=$(grep $country /path/to/other-big.log* | wc -l)
    echo $country $info1 $info2
done
```

I just removed unwanted piping.

Comment: This solution is a little more quicker than mine but still slow :\ The script runs on a server with (a lot of) memory. Why storing should not be a good idea ?

Comment: What are you expecting from `bash`, and your machines configuration...?

Comment: @Alex, If you are storing the whole content of file into a `variable`, then it will occupy much memory of RAM. It will cause other processes to slow down. I tested with `250M` file.

Comment: why put two `grep` for searching same country? like use `word=$(grep $country /path/to/*.log* | wc -l` batter.

Answer (score 2):

You are making unnecessary use of `cat` and `wc` in your script.

Try this script with `grep -c`:

```
for country in AT DE GB IT NO ZA
do
    info1=$(grep -c "$country" /path/to/big.log*)
    info2=$(grep -c "$country" /path/to/other-big.log*)
    echo "$country $info1 $info2"
done
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. However, `grep` outputs the filename followed by the number of lines: `/path/to/my-file:99`. How to keep the number only ?

Comment: If there are multiple files matching `/path/to/big.log*` which count you want? Do you want sum of all counts in that case?

Comment: `grep -c "$country" /path/to/big.log* | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2 | for country in AT DE GB IT NO ZA; do
    printf "%s " "$country"
    grep -c "$country"
done
```

Since you have multiple files, I'm thinking that's the fastest way to get the output you want. Someone correct me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental approach is wrong, as you are making a complete pass through each set of files for each country, rather than counting up every country on a single pass. This is a `bash` 4 script, but could be implemented in other, faster languages.

```
# Untested; consider this a description of the algorithm rather than
# ready-to-run code.
declare -A counts1=()
declare -A counts2=()
# Store per-country counts in an associative array for the first set of files
# E.g. counts[AT]=28, counts[DE]=93, etc.
for f in /path/to/big.log*; do
  while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ (AT|DE|GB|IT|NO|ZA) ]] && (( $counts1[${BASH_REMATCH[0]}]++ ))
  done  < $f
done
# Do the same for the second set of files
for f in /path/to/other-big.log*; do
  while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ (AT|DE|GB|IT|NO|ZA) ]] && (( $counts2[${BASH_REMATCH[0]}]++ ))
  done  < $f
done

# Output the results
for cc in AT DE GB IT NO ZA; do
    printf "%s %d %d\n"  $cc ${counts1[$cc]} ${counts2[$cc]}
done
```

Comment: Your fundamental algorithm exposes some advanced concept, from my point of view, of BASH. May you provide a less untested and more ready to run code ?